# Return value of sql query to textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I want to access the last value in database column increment it by 1 and show on a textbox
I used this code but nothing is displayed on text box what's wrong with this code?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (MAX[Account_No]  FROM addcustomer ", my);

int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Is there any kind of exception? Frankly I can't see a way by now how this could go wrong without an error. (By the way, you're not incrementing `result` in this code. Did you spare it out for brevity or forget?)

Comment: i try it likeSqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (MAX[Account_No]+1)  FROM addcustomer ", my);         but every time nothing displayed on textbox

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Account_No) + 1 FROM addcustomer` might work better. This does not solve your first problem though, so may I ask for an exception detail again? You might need to configure Visual Studio to notify you about exceptions, even if wrapped in try/catch blocks: Try *Debug*, *Exceptions* and check *Thrown* for *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*. This might show you additional information.

Comment: @user1577711 please add the code from before this block: what are you setting the value of `my` to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the sql statement as below

`SELECT MAX(Account_No) + 1  FROM addcustomer`

or increment after selecting value by code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No)  FROM addcustomer ", my);
int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) +1;
```

Final Code would be :

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No) + 1 FROM addcustomer", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); // do you get any Exception here?
}
```

Comment: both are not displaying any this. is there any way to check that sql qurry is returning somthing or not.

Comment: do you have number for `Account_No` column?

Comment: yes after all at least display some thing on textbox. thank you dear. i am searching it for a long time

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No)  FROM addcustomer ", my);
int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: still no working.i also try with [] brackets. no working.is some thing wrong with select query.

Comment: @user1577711 Wait a second.. What do you mean with _access last value_ ? `ExecuteScalar` gets first column value of first row. Please clarify your question.

Comment: The select code you have posted should return the highest account number in your database and display that number in the text box

Comment: i want to access last record no increment it by one and show on textbox. how i can do this

Comment: @user1577711 is your last record having max Account_No ? or how you going to identify last record?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly placed bracket. Change this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (MAX[Account_No]  FROM addcustomer ", my);
```

into that

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No)  FROM addcustomer ", my);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a bracket:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (MAX[Account_No]  FROM addcustomer ", my);
```

should be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No)  FROM addcustomer", my);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Account_No)  FROM addcustomer ", my);
```

Comment: this code is not workinh.i want to access last record no increment it by one and show on textbox. how i can do this